# strncat-like function breaks during test

Tags: c, string, pointers, undefined-behavior

I'm writing some library code, and one of my functions is invoking undefined behavior. I strongly suspect the error is in the test code, but I could be wrong. Here is a MCVE exhibiting the bug:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static inline char *
strncate(char * restrict dest, char const * restrict src, size_t n)
{
    strncat(dest, src, n);
    return dest + n;
}

#define BUFSZ 4096

int main(void){
    char buffer[BUFSZ];
    char *bufp = buffer;
    char const *strings[] = {
        "Hello",
        " ",
        "World",
        "!"
    };
    size_t stringslen = sizeof strings / sizeof *strings;
    assert(stringslen == 4); // always passes

    // 1
    bufp = strncate(bufp, strings[0], 5);
    bufp = strncate(bufp, strings[1], 1);
    bufp = strncate(bufp, strings[2], 5);
    bufp = strncate(bufp, strings[3], 1);

    assert(bufp - buffer == 12); // always passes
    printf("Result:   '%.*s'\n", (int)(bufp - buffer), buffer);
    puts  ("Expected: 'Hello World!'");
    assert(strncmp(buffer, "Hello World!", 12) == 0); // fails
    return 0;
}
```

Here is for loop that (1) replaces:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < stringslen; ++i) {
    size_t len = strlen(strings[i]);
    assert(len == 5 || len == 1);
    size_t currentoffset = bufp - buffer;

    if (currentoffset + len < BUFSZ)
        bufp = strncate(bufp, strings[i], len);
    else
        break;
}
```

I must be invoking UB at some point, as this is the (well, *one possible*) output:

```
$ make -B tstrncatb && ./tstrncatb
cc     tstrncatb.c   -o tstrncatb
Result:   'Hello Wor'
Expected: 'Hello World!'
tstrncatb.c:34: Assertion failed: 'strncmp(buffer, "Hello World!", 12) == 0'
Aborted
```

The problem is, I've been poring over this code for at least an hour now and I don't see any obvious logic error.

I don't believe it's a GCC bug, as clang exhibits the same behavior.

```
$ CC=clang make -B tstrncatb && ./tstrncatb
clang     tstrncatb.c   -o tstrncatb
Result:   'Hello Wor'
Expected: 'Hello World!'
tstrncatb.c:34: Assertion failed: 'strncmp(buffer, "Hello World!", 12) == 0'
Aborted
```

That said, the versions of GCC and clang I'm using are:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
braden ~/code/git/bradenlib/headers
$ clang --version
clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

Curiously, the code doesn't raise any warnings nor trip ASan or valgrind

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -fsanitize=address tstrncatb.c
braden ~/code/git/bradenlib/headers
$ ./a.out
Result:   '07Hello '
Expected: 'Hello World!'
tstrncatb.c:34: Assertion failed: 'strncmp(buffer, "Hello World!", 12) == 0'
Aborted
braden ~/code/git/bradenlib/headers
$ valgrind ./a.out
==3853767== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3853767== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3853767== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3853767== Command: ./a.out
==3853767==
==3853767==ASan runtime does not come first in initial library list; you should either...
==3853767==
==3853767== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3853767==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3853767==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==3853767==
==3853767== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3853767==
==3853767== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==3853767== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Additionally, when I run the MCVE on the environment at https://repl.it/languages/c, the bug does not reproduce. This is very strange because the MCVE really isn't much different from the full program. Therefore, since the MCVE may reproduce the problem in some environments and may not in others, here is the entire thing, in its current state which is exhibiting the bug on my platform:

tstrncatb.c (the test program):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "strncatb.h"
#include "sassert.h"

#define BUFSZ 4096

int main(void){
    char buffer[BUFSZ];
    char *bufp = buffer;
    char const *strings[] = {
        "Hello",
        " ",
        "World",
        "!"
    };
    size_t stringslen = sizeof strings / sizeof *strings;
    sassert(stringslen == 4);

#if 0
    for (size_t i = 0; i < stringslen; ++i) {
        size_t len = strlen(strings[i]);
        sassert(len == 5 || len == 1);
        size_t currentoffset = bufp - buffer;

        if (currentoffset + len < BUFSZ)
            bufp = strncate(bufp, strings[i], len);
        else
            break;
    }
#endif
    bufp = strncate(bufp, strings[0], 5);
    bufp = strncate(bufp, strings[1], 1);
    bufp = strncate(bufp, strings[2], 5);
    bufp = strncate(bufp, strings[3], 1);

    sassert(bufp - buffer == 12);
    printf("Result:   '%.*s'\n", (int)(bufp - buffer), buffer);
    puts  ("Expected: 'Hello World!'");
    sassert(strncmp(buffer, "Hello World!", 12) == 0);
    return 0;
}
```

strncatb.h (the header lib):

```
/*
 * Name:
 *     strncatb v1.0
 *
 * Synopsis:
 *     size_t  strncatb  (char * restrict dest, char const * restrict src, size_t n)
 *     size_t  strncate  (char * restrict dest, char const * restrict src, size_t n)
 *
 *     #define  strcatb  (dest, src)
 *     #define  strcate  (dest, src)
 *
 * Arguments:
 *     dest: destination string to copy to
 *     src:  source string to copy from
 *     n:    number of bytes to copy
 *
 * Description:
 *     `strncatb` and `strncate` concatenate two strings. Their behavior
 *     is the same as strncat with one exception (see return value)
 *
 *     The `strcatb` and `strcate` macros call their respective functions
 *     with strlen(src) as its third argument.
 *
 *     As in strncat, dest and src MUST NOT overlap. If they do, the
 *     behavior is undefined as per restrict semantics.
 *
 * Return Value:
 *     The b stands for bytes. The e stands for end. These suffixes refer
 *     to the return value
 *
 *     The b functions return the number of bytes copied
 *
 *     The e functions return a pointer to the byte after the last byte
 *     copied, so that calls can be nested or chained.
 *
 * Example:
 *     See tstrncatb.c
 */
#ifndef BRADENLIB_STRNCATB_H
#define BRADENLIB_STRNCATB_H

#include <string.h>

#define strcatb(dest, src) \
    strncatb(dest, src, strlen(src))

#define strcate(dest, src) \
    strncate(dest, src, strlen(src))

static inline size_t
strncatb(char * restrict dest, char const * restrict src, size_t n)
{
    strncat(dest, src, n);
    return n;
}

static inline char *
strncate(char * restrict dest, char const * restrict src, size_t n)
{
    strncat(dest, src, n);
    return dest + n;
}

#endif // BRADENLIB_STRNCATB_H
```

sassert.h (another header lib--I seriously doubt this is related to the issue):

```
/*
 * Name:
 *     sassert v1.0
 *
 * Synopsis:
 *     #define sassert(expr)
 *
 * Arguments:
 *     expr: expression to test
 *
 * Description:
 *     Simple assert macro, to replace stdc assert. Checks for NDEBUG
 *     macro
 */
#ifndef BRADENLIB_SASSERT_H
#define BRADENLIB_SASSERT_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef NDEBUG
#    define sassert(expr) (void)(expr)
#else
#    define sassert(expr) \
        if (!(expr)) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "%s:%u: Assertion failed: '%s'\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, #expr); \
            abort(); \
        }
#endif // NDEBUG

#endif // BRADENLIB_SASSERT_H
```

I'm happy to answer any questions or provide additional information about my environment. I don't ask a lot of questions on SO, so forgive me if I've committed a faux pas.

Comment: TL;DR For some reason, I got confused and thought strncat would copy *at* the pointer, so the test left the string uninitialized under the assumption that strncat wouldn't read dest. I somehow confused `strncpy` with `strncat`.

Comment: The code `strncat(dest, src, n); return dest + n;` does not give a good answer.  The value of `n` is the number of characters that may be added before overflowing the `dest` string, starting from the null byte at the end of the string that's already stored there.  If the string added is shorter than the maximum, there is no null padding (unlike `strncpy()`), so you have no clue what the returned pointer is actually pointing to in the general case (where the buffer is not already zeroed).  When the buffer is zeroed, you will return a pointer to some null byte, but it may not be the first null.

Comment: correct, because I was thinking in terms of strncpy semantics and got the names mixed up. I did in fact intend for the string to be copied in at the pointer with the exact number of bytes given, so what I really wanted was memcpy, but the lack of a "memcat" function combined with me getting the names mixed up led to me using strncat. I have since corrected the function, and the `*e` variant correctly copies one array of bytes to another and returns a pointer to the character after the last character copied. Good on you for explaining why strncat is the wrong function for this purpose, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very long question about a very trivial problem.

The solution:

```
    char buffer[BUFSZ] = {0};
```

Your `buffer` is not initialized and you invoke UB when appending the string to it.

https://godbolt.org/z/o6Mfv83M8

> e. This is very strange because the MCVE really isn't much different
> from the full program. Therefore, since the MCVE may reproduce the
> problem in some environments and may not in others

No, it is not strange - it is exactly how UB may express itself.

Comment: Is this to do with `strncat(3)`'s behavior? I left the buffer uninitialized intentionally, as the purpose of the exercise was to allow it to work with both zero-terminated and non-zero-terminated strings. I'm happy to use a different function or write my own if `strncat` with an unknown `dest` buffer is UB, because one of the parameters I set for strncatb and strncate is that the initial state of dest should not matter.

Comment: @BradenBest What is a "non-zero-terminated string"?

Comment: `I left the buffer uninitialized intentionally` you want UB - you get UB. Do not suspect tools!! They are good. Programmers are not good. It is impossible for the beginner like you to find compiler, linker or preprocessor bug

Comment: @jarmod that would be an array of char that is not guaranteed to end with \0, and functions that use it should accept an additional length argument to denote the length of said string

Comment: @0___________ [strncat(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncat) does not say anything about attempting to read `dest`. I don't see why leaving a buffer that is meant to be written to uninitialized would be undefined. The only way UB happens is if the uninitialized values are read.

Comment: @BradenBest OK, seems reasonable but you won't be able to use those 'strings' with any C library function that takes a string. For example `strncat` which needs to know the end of the destination string, of course. Suspect that's part of your issue (misunderstanding strncat).

Comment: I'm sure you know a lot more about C than I do. However, I am citing official standard library documentation here. "The strcat() function appends the src string to the dest string, overwriting the terminating null byte ('\0') at the end of dest, and then adds a terminating null byte. **The strings may not overlap**, and **the dest string must have enough space for the result.** If dest is not large enough, program behavior is unpredictable; buffer overruns are a favorite avenue for attacking secure programs." Emphasis mine. Both of the requirements stated for dest are satisfied.

Comment: @BradenBest you misunderstand. How will the library function know where the end of dest is? When you pass `dest`, you're passing the beginning of the destination string, not the end. If you were going to pass the end of dest, you wouldn't need strcat; you'd just use memcpy.

Comment: I also don't appreciate the attitude in that response, when I am merely asking how exactly this is UB and your response is to throw your experience at me and say I'm wrong rather than to explain how passing a buffer with an unknown state to a function that writes to said buffer is undefined, when the standard says nothing about said function reading from said buffer.

Comment: @jarmod *Oh.* I'm thinking of strcpy semantics. God I'm an idiot.

Comment: @BradenBest maybe this simple and trivial error gave me the wrong impression of your experience. Sorry. I can only judge from your question

Comment: @0___________ No worries. I gave your answer the upvote and checkmark. Have a nice day :)